# Library system in prolog

Tags: prolog, rules

I need help with a library system in prolog.

I tried to define all the books in my library this way:

```
book(['programming in logic'],
     [nm(k, clark), nm(f, mcCabe)], 
     ['programation'],
     ['editorial 123']).
```

And I tried to do a query for all programming books this way:

```
?- book(Title,Autgor,Genre,Editorial), 
   findall( Genre, (member('programation', Genre)), [G]).
```

but I need to suggest books by genre, author...

I also need to do statistics, most wanted book, genre most searched, author most wanted, things like that, but I'm not sure how to define the rules to do these queries. I have searched for examples, but only find things like family tree and I don't understand. If you could collaborate with examples for this exercise, I would appreciate too much.

Comment: If you just want help getting all the programming books, we can easily fix your query, but SO is not the right venue to give you a long general tutorial on how to perform queries with Prolog.

Comment: I want to transform that query into a rule, because I assume that's the query that I used to make suggestions..
but i want in the way sugestion_book(x,y):- blablabla
suggestion_author:-blablabla

Or is better leave as query?

Comment: Queries are really about interactive use of Prolog. You'll want to codify anything meaningful you do as a rule.

Answer (score 1):

For sure, modelling a library system could be a very complex topic.

I would suggest to start to learn RDF, for instance with SWI-Prolog, that has a very powerful library devoted to the task.

I just tried to use RDF to model objects simpler than biblio domain.

Anyway, I googled 'biblio ontology' and got some reasonable result, like [bibo](http://bibliontology.com/specification).

To start with, maybe you could consider some introductory material.